# Configuration Failed running SharePoint 2016 Preview product config wizard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, azure

I am currently running an Azure test environment looking to run SharePoint 2016 preview.  Running a DC(Win2012), SQL Server 14(Win 2012), and SharePoint 2016 preview image.  The issue is when I try to run the Production Configuration Wizard. The configuration fails indicating that an error occurred getting information about the domain/user at server `corp.contoso.com`.  The RPC Server is unavailable.  The acct has been set up with the correct DB permissions is a valid AD account and in the Administrator group for both SQL and SharePoint servers. Not able to pinpoint cause at this moment.

Comment: can you share the complete error detail?

Comment: Try connecting to the database with SQL Server Management Studio using the same account you are running the Configuration Wizard under. If you can't, then it is likely a firewall issue that is noted in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your problem? I had this issue:

3. Cannot connect to database master at SQL Server at {server_name}. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2015/08/30/sharepoint-2016-installation-errors/

there is a link on that page, but the solution for me was here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx